# Block rendering

Tags: nodes, blocks

Today I found a working php snippet to load block content into a node:

```
<?php
$block = block_load('block', '1');
$output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
print $output;
?>
```

Sadly I am not that good with php, and I could not figure out what to add, to remove the block title from rendering.
I have no need for that.

Help would be awesome!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to empty the `subject` of the block which is what Drupal uses to display the title:

```
// Set the block ID
$bid = 1;

// Load the block
$block = block_load('block', $bid);

// Get the output array
$output = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));

// Set the block subject to an empty string
$output['block_' . $bid]['#block']->subject = '';

// Output
print render($output);
```

Comment: If I do that I get a blank page. Nothing else renders, no header, no content, nothing...

Comment: @GergelyCsata I've re-written the answer, the code's tested and should work fine for what you want

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the title, if you go directly in the block config page and in the title section you add `<none>`

Comment: Of course this would also remove the block title when a block is displayed the normal way; I'm not sure if that is what @Gergely Csata is after.

Comment: In that case, I guess that one of theses function ``_block_render_blocks``, ``_block_get_renderable_array`` or will return something with ``['#title']`` and you can simply ``unset`` it.

Comment: Yea I wanted to get the block once without a title. But thank you for the general idea!